# dynamically build a form to post new data as JSON in flutter

Tags: json, flutter, post

I have a class to consume REST data from a web service that are Send via JSON.
I use a class to get the data in the right format. Class looks like that:

```
class BuildingSiteVisits {
  int? id;
  String? name;
  Float? lat;
  Float? long;

BuildingSiteVisits(
      {this.id,
      this.name,
      this.lat,
      this.long});

BuildingSiteVisits.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
id = json['id'];
    name = json['name'];
    lat = json['lat'];
    long = json['long'];
}

Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = <String, dynamic>{};
data['id'] = id;
    data['name'] = name;
    data['lat'] = lat;
    data['long'] = long;
    return data;
  }
}
```

The Original class has much more fields. How can I create a Form dynamical that can send correct JSON with correct Typecasts like quoted value for String, without quote for int and float and so on. For every field in the class, there should be a corresponding texteditfield. I have done it from a list of strings so far, but the web service will ignore the values because of wrong formatted fields.

Edit:
Extra information for better understanding. Thats how I build my Form at that Moment.

I have a List of Strings:

```
const List<String> buildingsiteFields = ['id','name','long','lat'];
```

With that list of string I Build my Fields with that Builder:

```
Widget _listView(List<String> fieldlist) {
    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: fieldlist.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        _controllers[fieldlist[index]] = TextEditingController();
        return Container(
          margin: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
          child: buildTextEditField(
              textEdetingController:
                  _controllers[fieldlist[index]] ?? TextEditingController(),
              label: fieldlist[index]),
        );
      },
    );
  }
```

Fields will be added to my Column widget and Texteditcontroller will be collected in my _controllers Map:

```
final Map<String, TextEditingController> _controllers = {};
```

Now for getting the Information back as JSON string I use the following code:

```
return ElevatedButton(
      onPressed: () async {
        var text = '{';
        _controllers.forEach((key, value) {
          text = '$text"$key":"${value.text}",';
        });
        text = text.substring(0, text.length - 1);
        text = '$text}';

        postData(dataTable: tableBuildingSiteVisit, jsonBody: text);
        setState(() {});
      },
    );
```

But with that I get every field as a String. But there will be Integers, bools etc. So my Question is, is it possible to use my Class instead of fieldstringlist and gather Information from Textcontrollers, like they should be. integer = integer, string = string an so on.

Answer (score 1):

the BuildingSiteVisits object is created outside the ListView widget, and its fields are updated in the onChanged callbacks of each buildTextEditField widget.

In the onPressed callback of the ElevatedButton, the toJson() method is called on the BuildingSiteVisits object to get a JSON object with the correct data types, which is then sent to the web service using the postData function.

```
Widget _listView() {
 final buildingSiteVisits = BuildingSiteVisits();

return ListView(
children: [
  buildTextEditField(
    textEditingController: TextEditingController(),
    label: 'id',
    onChanged: (value) => buildingSiteVisits.id = int.tryParse(value),
  ),
  buildTextEditField(
    textEditingController: TextEditingController(),
    label: 'name',
    onChanged: (value) => buildingSiteVisits.name = value,
  ),
  buildTextEditField(
    textEditingController: TextEditingController(),
    label: 'lat',
    onChanged: (value) => buildingSiteVisits.lat = double.tryParse(value),
  ),
  buildTextEditField(
    textEditingController: TextEditingController(),
    label: 'long',
    onChanged: (value) => buildingSiteVisits.long = double.tryParse(value),
  ),
  ElevatedButton(
    onPressed: () {
      final json = buildingSiteVisits.toJson();
      postData(dataTable: tableBuildingSiteVisit, jsonBody: json);
      setState(() {});
    },
    child: Text('Submit'),
   ),
  ],
 );
}
```

Comment: You get me wrong. The Focus of my Question is on the dynamic Part. I Know I can put a Field for every class Field on my Form, but I want that to be dynamic.

Comment: I am very sorry for not understanding. You want to make transactions of type dynamic elements.
Example : int a = dynamic a ; String b = dynamic b;

Comment: It's more like a conceptual question. At that moment, I have a list of String like this: const List<String> Fields = ['ID','name','long','lat'];
With that list I use a List view Builder to build the Fields with a texteditcontroller. I will add the code to the Question for better understanding.

Comment: Yes, it is possible to use your BuildingSiteVisits class to gather information from the TextEditingController objects and create a JSON object with the correct data types.

First, you need to create an instance of the BuildingSiteVisits class and initialize its fields with the values from the TextEditingController objects. You can do this by iterating through the _controllers map and setting the corresponding field in the BuildingSiteVisits object.Then, you can call the toJson() method on the BuildingSiteVisits object to get a JSON object with the correct data types.